# How to make Zest nodes move from their current location after a change?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, zest

When I first populate a graph, all the nodes appear stacked on the top-left corner. When I invoke `applyLayout()` on the graph, the nodes move to the appropriate location with a nice animation. However, after I change the graph (remove some nodes, adds others) and invoke `applyLayout()` again, all the nodes move to their appropriate location, but they start at the top-left corner again.

Is there a way to make the nodes move *from their current location* to the new one, without having them reset to the top-left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way. However, in the latest version of Zest (see [GEF 4 Update Sites](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/GEF4#Update_Sites)), animation is disabled by default. This should at least result in the new layout appearing in the correct place directly.